# Tuning Linux NFSv4 client and server for high latency links?

Tags: nfs

Does Linux NFSv4 (not NFSv3/NFSv2) have tunables to improve the latency (i.e. find . -ls speed on NFSv4 file systems) over high latency satellite links?

find . -ls on NFSv4 over satellite link is very slow. Bandwidth is very good, just find . -ls is horribly slow.

Comment: `find . -ls` does a `stat` call per file, which is of course an extra roundtrip over high latency link. To avoid that,  try to instruct the client (kernel) to use READDIR and cache the result for a longer period with `acregmin` mount option.